# Why does AVAudioPlayer does not play?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

**We developed this iOS scenario:**

1) iOS App schedules local push notification
2) Push is a trigger to start AVAudioPlayer audio playing - even if the iPhone is locked (app in background)

Now there are two scenarios:

**a) Time difference between push scheduling is more than 3 hours:**
Audio does start playing after unlocking and starting the app

**b) Time difference between push scheduling is less than 3 hours:**
Audio does start playing even without unlocking

We want **case b** as default case. Does iOS stop/freeze our application after some hours? Interesting: On indian devices there does not seem to be case a - even if time difference is more than 12 hours.

Any ideas?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Did you integrate background execution? Otherwise the app will be suspended after a while.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Answer (score 0):

Once didReceiveLocalNotification method triggered in appdelegate, then trigger one method in appdelegate or in global then use below code to play audio file using AVAudioPlayer in background or device lock

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@“filename”
                                                          ofType:@“type”];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL
                                                error:nil];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];


player.numberOfLoops = -1; //Infinite

[player prepareToPlay];

[player play];
```